# Interaction with SharePoint with 2FA enabled via SharePoint CSOM

Tags: c#, authentication, exception, sharepoint, connection

I need to write a lib to work with Sharpoint. Microsoft authenticator is used for 2FA. I encountered problems already at the stage of connecting to the Sharpoint. I assume that this is due to the fact that 2FA is enabled on the Sharpoint.

This is the exception I get:

```
Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) did not get a response from the Login server.
```

The code I have:

```
public class SharePointHandler
{
    private ClientContext clientContext;

    public SharePointHandler(string siteUrl, string libraryName, string username, string password, string token)
    {
        var SPOCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, ToSecureString(password));
        clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

        clientContext.Credentials = SPOCredentials;
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // here exception
    }

    private static System.Security.SecureString ToSecureString(string password)
    {
        System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        secureString.AppendChar(c);

        return secureString;
    }
}
```

Maybe someone has encountered this and can tell me how to bypass 2fa or maybe this is not the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [register SharePoint app only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs) first. The you could use following code to connect sharepoint

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var appCred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
{
    e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + appCred.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" })).Token;
};
```